# Elasticsearch '[bool] failed to parse field [filter]'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I'm trying to solve parsing exception of my search query.
*"type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
"reason" : "[18:9] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]"*
I hope someone can help me
thanks

```
GET /g20/_search
{ "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {"geo_shape": {
          "location": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "envelope",
              "coordinates": [
                [39,-77],
                [38,-76]
              ]
            },
            "relation": "within"
          }
        }
          
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reverse the coordinate order b/c the coordinates you've provided are in Antarctica, not around D.C. as you likely intentioned:

```
GET /g20/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_shape": {
            "location": {
              "shape": {
                "type": "envelope",
                "coordinates": [
                  [ -77, 39 ],
                  [ -76, 38 ]
                ]
              },
              "relation": "within"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the [envelope spec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#_envelope), `lon` is followed by `lat`.